# Tkinter changing the height of a button

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

Hi I am trying to create a button with the following features:

```
B_home = ttk.Button(self, width=17, height=20, text='Home', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(main_menu))
```

When I run my code, I get an error saying: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height".

I have read through tkinter documentation and the height parameter does indeed exist (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm), so why is this happening?

It should also be mentioned that when I run my code without the height parameter, it works just fine.

Comment: tkinter and ttk are two separate libraries. While ttk includes many of the same classes as tkinter, they have different behaviors. The ttk button simply doesn't support a `height` attribute.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay! But how can I create a button with the same modern look as with using the ttk library, with the tk library.

Comment: Well, for one, a modern interface doesn't have buttons that are 20 characters tall. The choice of tk versus ttk is one of tradeoffs - either you have ultimate configurability with tk, or less configurability with a more modern look with ttk.